# Is there any basis to gift or present giving on specifically on Eid ul Fitr?

Tags: islamic-basis, eid

Is there any basis to gift or present giving on specifically on Eid ul Fitr?

Please provide references from the Quran and Sunnah if any.

Jazak Allah

Comment: @Mhmd I couldn't leave a comment on that answer so leaving comment here. You provide a good answer but my issue is that gift giving should not be limited specifically on Eid as, like you say in your answer, this was not practiced by our Prophet and the Sahaba.

Comment: Of course it shouldn't, but some days should be differentiated from others. For example, Jumaa day should not be treated the same as other days.

Comment: I agree, on a Jumaa there are special prayers as told by our Prophet peace be upon him but is there also any sunnah or hadith which supports gift/present giving specifically on Eid?

Comment: Yes, please see this question: http://islamqa.info/en/130948